# Book length indicator for Kindle Paperwhite firmware 5.7.2.1

Tags: kindle, kindle-paperwhite, firmware

My Kindle Paperwhite has been updated (automatically) to firmware 5.7.2.1

In the old firmware the length of the book was indicated by the number of dots below the book title. Bold dots indicated my reading process:

> **.....**.........

In the new firmware nothing indicates the length  of the book, only the following is printed:

> 42% READ

Is there a way to change back to the old style? I really liked the way it showed the relative length of the books.

Comment: everybody is complaining about new firmware. I dont receive the update yet so I cannot answer to your question. You can go back to old home view following this instruction: http://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/6456/kindle-paperwhite-ver-5-7-2-1-how-to-bring-back-one-click-book-open

Comment: I did go back to the old view. The old view is also changed a bit, so no dots in the old view.

Comment: Did you ask if there is anyway to downgrade? maybe if you download the previous bin and run it from kindle, then it works?

Comment: I don't want to downgrade (and I don't think it's possible, it would upgrade again automatically), I'd like to use the new firmware but still see the dots.

Comment: I also upgraded yesterday. I think customization as you want is not possible. With kindle you are always forced to do what amazon wants to do.I didnt want to upgrade but I couldnt! :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of complaints the dots were brought back in the latest 5.8.1 firmware update for [PW2](http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/ref=hp_left_cn?nodeId=201307450) and [PW3](http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=201756220) Kindles, which you might need to manually download from the Amazon website.

(You can only downgrade to a previous version, if your Kindle had the latest jailbreak installed.)

Answer (score 0):

In the font selection (where yotu can change the size of your font, there is now a tab where you can choose reading progress options within the book.

Comment: That only changes the info at the lower left corner of the page. It does not bring back the old book length indicator dots.