# Kindle paperwhite ver.5.7.2.1 - how to bring back one-click book open?

Tags: amazon, kindle-paperwhite, library, send-to-kindle

I've recently upgraded (automatically) my PW2 to the specified software version and I just hate some of the new "features" of it. For example(the worst thing I found and could not fix yet), the book library. In my library (95% received via email feature) I have a lot of books that are read, multiple started and a gigantic amount of unread books, that are listed after every other mentioned type. Now, previously I just needed to scroll down to the right one, click on it and it opened. Now, I need to find it (on, for example, page 15), click on it, scroll back to the first page of the list and click again. Why? As it seems, the book gets "downloaded" again, for some reason, then since it's the last downloaded it appears the first one in the list and only after that I may open it. Why the hell did Amazon implement this - I can't even imagine, but maybe anyone knows how to always have them downloaded automatically now?

Answer (score 1):

GO back to previous home screen menu following these steps:

1. Go to home screen and press menu button (It is on top right of screen)
2. Select **settings**
3. Select **device options**
4. Select **personalize your kindle**
5. Select **advanced options**
6. Turn off **home screen view**

and hopefully now you are back to your old screen view.

Let me know if it worked.

Comment: Sorry but no, that is not related to the question. What I really need is a way to downloaded a book that is cloud-stored AND open it right away. Now a "download" and an "open" feature are separate, though previous software had them grouped in one task. I'm not sure if this is possible to return since I've tried almost every available option before posting the question (including turning off the home screen view option since I disliked the new view) and neither worked.

Comment: In your home screen you have two options: All and downloaded. If you select All, then you can access books on cloud, isn't it? take a look at screenshot: http://goodereader.com/blog/uploads/images/screenshot_2016_02_13T14_44_23-0500.png

Comment: Correct. But previous SW alowed me to download and open a book (that is listed in all and is not downloaded yet) in one click, and now only downloaded books are opened right away. So I select All, click a "newly" received book (that I sent 3 months ago) and my sorting is set to "recent books first" - the book gets downloaded and "jumps" to the top of the list from the page it was on when I already found it. Previous soft just downloaded and opened it, I did not have to find the book on page 12 to download then on page 1 to open.

Comment: as I didnt download this update yet, i cannot answer you for this specific matter. Why dont try to ask from amazon online support (chat / phone / email). chat always answer immediately

Comment: That's actually a great advice, I've started to get the feeling that I would have to email them anyway so I will try to ask them. Will write an answer when I'll get it. Thank You for Your time!

Comment: You are welcome. Please write here the result of your conversation so that future users can benefit it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your Kindle qualifies, but Amazon got enough complaints about the recent upgrade to OS 5.0, that certain Kindles qualify to have the software returned to its prior operating system. My Kindle 6 HD was horrible in OS5, so I contacted Amazon and rolled it back. They had to read me a stupid paper describing all the 'benefits' of the new operating system and made me agree before downgrading my Kindle, but they did it. Give it a shot!

Answer (score -1):

You have to click the 'downloaded' button in the upper left corner. It will solve your problem.

Comment: Do you have a bit more information on how this solves the repeated download the OP is experiencing?

Comment: Where is this button? Have a screenshot?